# simulation for vehicle routing

Tags: graph, routes, simulation, modeling, platform

I'm working on a project about graph-based Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem with multiple Time windows.
so basically the road network I'm using is graph based ( nodes and weighted edges). 
I wanted a good simulation platform to simulate my work. I already have problem formulation  ( math equations ) and now I'm stuck. 
I want a simulation platform that has graph toolbox and showing the road network and vehicles and gives me results of routing schedules of each vehicle and minimum routing time. ( java or c#) if any! 
I hope that's clear enough.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's reasonably clear.  It's also explicitly off-topic for SO.  Please read the [guidelines for questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Note item #4 in particular.

Comment: Thanks @pjs, I didn't read the guidelines before. Where can I ask such questions?